# how can i access this variable outside the file

Tags: javascript, variables, global

Basically i have two .js files ,let it is A.js and B.js and i have code like this

***A.js***

```
    function details(age,address,name){ 
      //some code 
      //some code

      getData(age);

      //some code
    }

function getData(ag){
      return ag;
}
```

**B.js**

here how can i access that getData(?) ??? , i don't want to use global variable and i just want to know is it possible in any way or choosing global variable is last option.

Comment: Those functions look like global functions already, if that's client-side code.

Comment: Do you want to access getDate(), which is in A.js from B.js file?

Comment: yes i want to access it from B.js and details() does not return age only ,it is doing its own functionality. And in B.js i just want the age .i.e. i want to call getData() without giving any argument to it ,as well as want age in return.

Comment: did you export your details() function?

Comment: can you please explain me what "export" means @alexfrize

Comment: i thought you're using nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Until now, plain JavaScript doesn't provide a built-in namespace management for JS resources.
Recently, [import feature appeared](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import).

> The import statement is used to import functions, objects, or
>   primitives which are defined in and exported by an external module,
>   script, or the like.

But beware :

> This feature is only just beginning to be implemented in browsers
>   natively at this time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as
>   the Traceur Compiler, Babel, Rollup, and Webpack.

In `A.js`, you could export `getData()` as clients need it :

```
function details(age,address,name){ 
      //some code 
      //some code

      getData(age);

      //some code
    }

export function getData(ag){
      return ag;
}
```

and in the client code could import it :

```
import { getData} from '/modules/A.js';

getData(...);
```

---

If you want to keep plain JS fully supported, a classic workaround used by the authors of JS libraries is using a single global variable that holds all public resources that the client needs.
In this way, you reduce the risk to have conflict with other libraries or client resources.

If you can change the code of these files, you could define a single global variable :

```
var myNameSpace = {

     details : function(age,address,name){ 
      //some code 
      //some code

      getData(age);

      //some code
    },

    getData : function getData(ag){
          return ag;
    }

   ....

};
```

And access to the function by prefixing with the single global variable : `myNameSpace`.

```
myNameSpace.getData(...);
```

Comment: i don't want to use global in any way.

Comment: Namespacing is a very valid JS pattern.

Comment: this is what i want to know ,it is possible in any way or not ,without using global variable.

Comment: You can use modules and imports but it is experimental.

Comment: in your example when you are calling getData(...) ,what are these "..." means ,  it is actually ... or i have to replace it with passing no. of parameters.@davidxxx

Comment: These are actual arguments.

Answer (score 0):

In your `A.js` file store the returning data that is `ag` in local/session storage.
You can access this data in `B.js` which will be in local/session storage.

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");
```